# Fold with previous element

Tags: scala, fold

Given `val as: Seq[Int] = ...`

A lot of times I need to apply an operation to two consecutive elements, e.g.

By the way I don't like

```
for (i <- 1 until as.size) {
  // do something with as(i) and as(i - 1)
}
```

Or by another

```
as.tail.foldLeft((0, as.head)) { (acc, e) =>
  // do something with acc._2 and e 
  // and try to not forget returning (_, e) 
}
```

How do I writer better code for this scenario?

Comment: you can explore sliding, e.g. breaking up your sequence into pairs and mapping over them `as.sliding(2).map { case prev +: next +: _ => func(prev, next) }`

Comment: I've never missed this function. You're sure you need it *often*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could `zip` the sequence `as` with its own `tail`:

```
for ((prev, curr) <- as zip as.tail) {
  // do something with `prev` and `curr`
}
```

Or you could use `sliding`:

```
for (window <- as.sliding(2)) {
  val prev = window(0)
  val curr = window(1)
  // do something with `prev` and `curr`
}
```

Comment: I wonder if we could possibly make an overloaded foldLeft function that also passes the previous element

Comment: @JordanCutler One does not simply *overload* `foldLeft` ;) because `foldLeft` is somewhat of a mathematical constant, like `Pi`. But you could of course write a fused `zipWithTailFoldLeft`, why not. It just doesn't seem like too many people are missing it. It seems somewhat unnatural, because it's unclear where the number `2` comes from.

Comment: check my answer now let me know what your opinion is

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to supply the head of your sequence to every subsequent element.

```
val sq:Seq[Int] = Seq(. . .)

sq.headOption.fold(sq){hd =>
  sq.tail.map(/*map() or fold() with the hd value*/)
}
```

Note that this is safe for collections of 1 or zero elements.

Answer (score 1):

Can make your own fold which supports previous element. 
Safe with 1 or zero element collections.

```
  def foldLeftWithPrevious[A, B](as: Seq[A], accumulator: B)(f: (B, A, A) => B): B = {
    @scala.annotation.tailrec
    def foldLeftInner(list2: Seq[A], previous: A, accumulator: B, f: (B, A, A) => B): B = {
      if (list2.isEmpty) accumulator
      else foldLeftInner(list2.tail, list2.head, f(accumulator, previous, list2.head), f)
    }

    if (as.length <= 1) accumulator
    else foldLeftInner(as.tail, as.head, accumulator, f)
  }
```

Feel free to test it with this snippet.

```
val foldLeftTest = Seq(1)
  foldLeftWithPrevious(foldLeftTest, 0)((accum, previous, current) => {
    println("accum = " + accum)
    println("previous = " + previous)
    println("current = " + current)
    println("accum will be... " + accum + " + " + previous + " + " + current)
    println("which is... " + (accum + previous + current))
    accum + previous + current
  })
```

Comment: It claims to accept an arbitrary `Seq[A]` in the signature, but then does `List`-specific pattern matching with `::` inside. For all non-lists, it produces match errors. Furthermore: the nested method does not need block-syntax, so `f` does not need a separate variable list; The name of the nested method seems way too long for a 8 line method; You could add `@annotation.tailrec` to make it clear that the method has this nice property.

Comment: Fixed (aside from the "f does not need a separate variable list", trying to still figure out what you mean). Thanks @AndreyTyukin

Comment: I meant "parameter list", sorry: `foldLeftInner(list2: List[A], previous: A, accumulator: B, f: (B, A, A) => B)` has fewer parentheses, and only one list of parameters. You don't use the block notation anyway, so...

Comment: Good note! Fixed x2 :)

Comment: Now it *usually* does not crash with a match exception, but the signature still invokes the impression as if it could work with [`Stream`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.3/scala/collection/immutable/Stream.html), because `Stream` is `Seq`. In general, it looks as if it could work on any `Seq` *directly*, without internal conversion. And the nested method seems to be in a state of denial, because it attempts to hold on to the illusion that it could work with a general `Seq` 8] Should either change `Seq` to something more restricted, or get rid of `Nil` and `::` somehow.

Comment: Hmmm.. so you're saying it crashes when you pass a Stream? Mine seems to be working with a Stream created with `val stream = Stream(1,2,3,4)` What version of scala are you running? Im 2.12.1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166775/discussion-between-andrey-tyukin-and-jordan-cutler).